# Cryptography Online Education

Tags: cryptography, professional-education

Do the security experts at IT Security have a preference between the two cryptography courses offered by [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto) (Stanford), "Cryptography I" and [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs387), "Applied Cryptography"?

I am seeking an introductory-level course, and have a modest amount of experience with Java, macros, and CS in general.

Comment: I've heard a lot of praise for the coursera crypto course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there can be an objective answer to that question. So, here is a *subjective* answer: the Coursera course is by [Dan Boneh](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/), so it cannot be bad.

**Note:** cryptography is a rather advanced topic. To really get the hang of it, you need to know a bit of maths, especially linear algebra and some probabilities.

Comment: I enjoyed the beginning of Cryptography I, but had to drop out because of work work work. It was challenging and interesting.